# C# get result from existing restapi using basic authorization and posting json content

Tags: c#, json, .net, httpclient, basic-authentication

I searched internet a few days and got no luck. I thought it must be simple, but turns out no.
I use .netfx4.5.2. It is a C# desktop app.

```
        string username = "username";
        string password = "password";
        string apiUrl = "https://.../auth/token";

        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            UseCookies = false
        };

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"))
            );

            var requestContent = new StringContent(
                "{ \"terminal_id\": \"95000059\" }",
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            );


            try
            {
                var response = httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, requestContent).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    richTextBox1.Text = responseContent;
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = $"Failed to get token. Status code: {response.StatusCode}";
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

It returns error msg as follows:

```
  One or more errors occurred.System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. --->
  System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
  System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

It works fine on Postman. Please see the postman ss:
[image]
[image]

Pls help me guys!
Regards
Orgil.D

Comment: One or more errors ocurred error message is too brief. Have you try to debug your code to check the exception log in detailed? If yes, share the exception log.

Comment: @YongShun debug exception log is here I guess: One or more errors occurred.System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

I found out that one row of code solves my problem:

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)2048;
```

But I still don't understand what this line doing!
Anyway it works now